# css-grid media queries not responding

Tags: css, css-grid

I am working with grid, and for some reason, using `max-width` in the media query seems to do nothing. code below:

**Code:**

```css
body {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

#content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-areas: 'header header header header' 'block_1 block_1 block_2 block_2'
}

@media only screen and (max-width:700px) {
  #content {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
    grid-gap: 1rem;
    grid-template-areas: 'header' 'block_1' 'block_2'
  }
}

#content>* {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  height: 150px;
}

.block_1 {
  grid-area: block_1;
  height: 150px;
}

.block_2 {
  grid-area: block_2;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="master.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id='content'>
    <div class='header'>Header</div>
    <div class='block_1'>Header</div>
    <div class='block_2'>Header</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I expect the 2 block classes to stack on top of each other at 699px and below. However, they do not seem to want to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will also need to change `grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);` to make that grid take full width.

```css
body {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

#content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-areas: 'header header header header' 'block_1 block_1 block_2 block_2'
}

@media only screen and (max-width:700px) {
  #content {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
    grid-gap: 1rem;
    grid-template-areas: 'header' 'block_1' 'block_2'
  }
}

#content>* {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  height: 150px;
}

.block_1 {
  grid-area: block_1;
  height: 150px;
}

.block_2 {
  grid-area: block_2;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="master.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id='content'>
    <div class='header'>Header</div>
    <div class='block_1'>Header</div>
    <div class='block_2'>Header</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```